# Java - formatting string output to display in a TextArea

Tags: java, string

I've got 2 fields to display to a textarea in a simple java application I'm writing to learn the swing library.

Basically, this small app has a few buttons I can click and the values for each button get stored in an ArrayList. When I press "calculate", I want to output the names, values, and a sum of the numeric values at the bottom of the output.

For example, element 1 in the ArrayList would be an object with a name of "ItemOne" and a value of 12. Element 2 would be an object with the name "ItemTwoHasALongName" and a value of 15.

I want to output the following to a textarea:

```
ItemOne                15
ItemTwoHasALongName    12

Total: 27
```

I have no problem outputting the values, but I have trouble getting the formatting to be correct. Here's what I have:

```
for (MyItemObjects itemObject : objItemObjects){
    this.billTextArea.append(itemObject.getItemName() + "          " + itemObject.GetItemCost());
    total += itemObject.getmCost();
}

this.textArea.append("Total: $" + Total + "\n");
```

Now, I know I'm not left padding the item cost in the above example. Whenever I try to, I get awful looking output that isn't correct.

Here's an example of how I'm trying to format the output as a string, then I append the string to the text area. How can I have the item name be left justified, and the item cost padded left by as many spaces as necessary (based on the item name's length) to get the cost to be in line as a column for each line?

```
String strLine = String.format("%" + maxLineLength + "s%", itemObject.getItemName() + "          " + itemObject.GetItemCost());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to do what you're asking:

1. Use a JLabel with HTML instead of a JTextArea.  This is probably the easiest approach.  If you start your text with <html>, then you can use stacked <div> elements with nested <span> and use CSS to place the text.  It's only HTML 3.2 and CSS *almost* 2, but it will probably be enough to align the costs.
2. If you really want it to look and behave like a text area, don't use a JTextArea, use a kind of JEditorPane with e.g. the HTMLEditorKit and build HTML to produce the text you want to produce.  See #1.
3. If you really want to use a JTextArea, you can use the FontMetrics object to measure the width of a string and determine how many spaces/etc. you need to add to put the cost in its place.  There's a tutorial here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

i'm no swing expert, but i think you can set textarea to use a BoxLayout or similar and place itemObject.getItemName() in one cell and itemObject.getItemCost() in another.

Comment: I've actually tried setting columns in the text area, but cannot figure out how to output to column 1 and column 2. Even with googling it.